# Joomla ! A MVC framework or CMS?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, content-management-system

Sorry.i am new to joomla.Is there anyone who could tell me whether joomla is mvc framework or content management system?? I am confused.kind regards

Comment: if would have gone to their [**website**](http://www.joomla.org/) you would have read CMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public facing presence is of [Joomla! the CMS](http://joomla.org) - architecturally though since version 1.6 it's been moving to Joomla! the CMS [[GitHub]](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms) which sits on top of the Joomla! Platform [[GitHub]](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/).

The idea is to leverage all the good in the framework for applications other than the original CMS functionality. So, you can [create stand alone applications](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_create_a_stand-alone_application_using_the_Joomla!_Platform) using the platform, they don't even have to be web applications. e.g. we have several small apps that are fired from `cron` to run background tasks that leverage the platform framework and the models etc of our larger Joomla components.

Answer (score 3):

Joomla is a content management system built using the MVC pattern. Joomla provide interfaces and APIs to let you extend it and build addons to add more feature to it. So some people define it as a framework too